# Local FDR from p-values in R 3.1.1

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a package to calculate Efron's local FDR for a series of tests.  I have over 1000 covariates, so multiple correction is definitely in order.

Looking for local FDR is see the locfdr package is no longer available on CRAN.  Any idea why it was removed?  This seems the most closely related to the original publication of local FDR.

I did find fdrtool, but it cannot calculate local FDR from p-values.  Other packages I've found are not available for 3.1.1 - LocalFDR, localFDR, kerfdr, twilight.  Of course all these packages use slightly different methods.  Even if I could get to them, which to choose?

Comment: Archived versions are available here http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/locfdr/ you can download and `install.packages(file, repos = NULL, type="source")`. You may want to investigate why the package was removed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I did get the archived version, installed it, and it is working.  It is dated Feb 2011, though, which makes me wonder why it is so out of date, why it was pulled, etc.  Also there's a long list of other packages that are no longer on CRAN as well - nomi, LocalFDR, kerfdr, localFDR...  Seems odd so many tools that do the same thing are all missing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the methods so can't comment, but it certainly doesn't seem like a simple coincidence.

Comment: `twilight` package has moved to `bioconductor`. To install use `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")` then `biocLite("twilight")`. A quick look at the `bioconductor` site suggets there are several other packages that may help http://www.bioconductor.org/help/search/index.html?q=false+discovery+rate

Comment: The `fdrtool`-package can also do it (I've edited my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `twilight` package can do this (as also suggested in the comments). It's easy to use as demonstrated below and quite clear vignettes are available at bioconductor.

First we install the package.

```
# Install twilight
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("twilight")
```

Next, we simulate some test-scores and p-values.

```
# Simulate p p-values
set.seed(1)
p <- 10000 # Number of "genes"
prob <- 0.2 # Proportion of true alternatives

# Simulate draws from null (=0) or alternatives (=1)
null <- rbinom(p, size = 1, prob = prob) 
# Simulate some t-scores, all non-null genes have an effect of 2
t.val <- (1-null)*rt(p, df = 15) + null*rt(p, df = 15, ncp = 2)
# Compute p-values
p.val <- 2*pt(-abs(t.val), df = 15)

# Plot the results
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
hist(t.val, breaks = 70, col = "grey",
     xlim = c(-10, 10), prob = TRUE, ylim = c(0, .35))
hist(p.val, breaks = 70, prob = TRUE)
```

[image: Imgur]

Next we load the library and run the fdr analysis:

```
library(twilight)
ans <- twilight(p.val)
```

We see that the estimate of the true alternative proportion is quite good:

```
print(1 - ans$pi0)
#[1] 0.1529
print(prob)
#[1] 0.2
```

The package reorders the p-values, q-values, and fdr-values in increasing order, so we do a trick to reconstruct the original order.

```
o <- order(order(p.val)) 
fdr <- ans$result$fdr[o]
plot(p.val, fdr, pch = 16, col = "red", cex = .2)
```

[image: Imgur]

Lastly, we can crosstabulate the significant against the true:

```
table(estimate = fdr < 0.5, truth = as.logical(null))
#        truth
#estimate FALSE TRUE
#   FALSE  7564 1172
#   TRUE    368  896
```

Hence, we have an accuracy of 84.6 % in this toy-example. I hope this helps. The `twilight` function also features bootstrapped CIs for the fdr which you'll find in `?twilight` along with further references.

**Edit**
It seems that the `fdrtool` package (which is on CRAN) actually can compute the local fdr from p-values. In our case we do the following:

```
library("fdrtool")
fdr <- fdrtool(p.val, statistic="pvalue")
fdr$lfdr # The local fdr values
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the great example.  This helps tremendously!

Comment: I'm more interested in "Any idea why it was removed?"

Comment: @daj No idaa. I cannot find any information. But the `fdrtool` package is also an option (as seen in my edited answer).

Comment: I had used fdrtool (mentioned in my original post) but I didn't find that it did local fdr.  I see that now - thanks again!  Regarding that package, I see fdr listed as q-values - do we know if this is FDR as defined by Benjamini-Hochberg or is it Storey's q-values?  I've always been confused at the mixed terminology and I've tried to use FDR for the BH method and q-value for the Storey method.